# Is there a better way to write out long JavaScript "if" blocks

Tags: javascript, if-statement

The following if-block seems really inefficient. I imagine there is a better way to do this.
This will be used to set parameters in a graphics library. eg camera position, objects position, and others.
Additionally, a generic solution is welcome.

```js
const queryString = window.location.search;
const urlParameter = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
//this code is what my question is about V
if (urlParameter.has("a")) {
  a = parseInt(urlParameter.get("a"));
}
if (urlParameter.has("b")) {
  b = parseInt(urlParameter.get("b"));
}
if (urlParameter.has("c")) {
  c = parseInt(urlParameter.get("c"));
}
if (urlParameter.has("d")) {
  d = parseInt(urlParameter.get("d"));
}
//^
```

Note: I am fairly inexperienced with JavaScript, and mainly use it for hobby projects.

Comment: Answer partially depends on what your next step is with regard to those variables. Tell us more about your use case

Comment: for each exists in javascript

Comment: Any time you find yourself repeating code like this you should be thinking "Can I make this a function?" Or, for certain cases, "Can I make this a loop?" The answer to both is usually "Yes."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array with the input parameter names an iterate over it.

But since you cannot assign dynamic variable names in JavaScript, you will need to change your output slightly to use an object:

```
const allowedParameters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

const parsedParameters = {};

allowedParameters.forEach((key)=> {
  if (urlParameter.has(key)) {
    parsedParameters[key] = parseInt(urlParameter.get(key));
  }
});

// To use the values just access each key in the parsedParameters object:

console.log(parsedParameters.a);
```

Comment: This will result in `NaN` for the props in `parsedParameters` which are not in the `urlParameter` maplike object.

Comment: For sure. I forgot the .has() check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing them as individual variables, you are probably better of storing them in an object or Map instance. This allows for a more dynamic approach when setting/getting the values.

```
const allowedParameters = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
const values = {};
for (const paramName of allowedParameters) {
  if (urlParameter.has(paramName)) {
    values[paramName] = parseInt(urlParameter.get(paramName));
  }
}
```

You can then access the values through `values.a` (or `values["a"]`), `values.b`, etc.

---

If you do want to store them as individual variables you could use destructuring assignment, this does assume that the variables are not defined beforehand.

```
const [a, b, c, d] = ["a", "b", "c", "d"].map((paramName) => {
  if (urlParameter.has(paramName)) {
    return parseInt(urlParameter.get(paramName));
  }
});
```

The above will set `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` regardless of their presence in `urlParameter`. If they are not present they will be set to `undefined`, because the `map()` callback returns `undefined` if not present (it has no return value).

Meaning that this solution won't work if `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are already defined, and you only want to redefine them if present.

---

This can be solved with the solution below, but this will only work when redefining variables, not if you are initializing them for the first time.

```
[a, b, c, d] = Object.entries({ a, b, c, d }).map((paramName, oldValue) => {
  if (urlParameter.has(paramName)) {
    return parseInt(urlParameter.get(paramName));
  } else {
    return oldValue;
  }
});
```